# Is there a reason my youtube app gives me access to one youtube channel but not another?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

I created a youtube app in console.developers.google.com that has the youtube data, youtube analytics and youtube reporting apis enabled. I also have access to multiple youtube channels that I'm hoping to automate some reports. several youtube channels I can login to with my app with no problem, but one in particular returns a message saying "Google has disabled this app" and I don't know why. It works will all channels but one, is there some permission that needs to be set in this particular one?

Comment: Is this the correct forum for this question?

Comment: Jacob, please spend another few seconds when reviewing Stack's *recommended* tags. In this case, you accepted the [tag:r] tag, which is for the [R programming language](https://www.r-project.org/), almost certainly not what you're using here. I agree with @Peter that your question is likely more suited for another Stack site, perhaps [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), not for StackOverflow (which is about *programming*).

Comment: I posted the question here because I reached out to Google about this question, and they said they'd only answer it on Stack Overflow, so I put the same exact question here. It is programming related, I'm using R and httr to pull in this data, but I can see your point